# Source control checkin internal rules gone too far?

Tags: svn, deployment, tfs

So, some people at my work are trying enforce new rules when we check in files.
For reference I use VS 2012, C# and TFS.

Currently we make changes to x files in a project, then once its all working locally we checkin non breaking changes, ready for deployment. When we check in x files at once, we leave one general sweeping comment about the change.

There is a push from the people deploying the code from dev to staging that each file be checked in one at a time with a specific comment, and that in our change control (we use jira) we have to say all the .cs files (and line numbers) of everything we changed.

Currently we say in jira what the changes affect, and what .dll files to push.

I think that naming each line / cs file is overkill. Also if you wnat to rollback changesets with TFS, checking in files one at a time could be a nightmare to undo.
Because you end up with some files coded against different versions of other files.

But that said, I don;t have to deploy from dev => staging => production, only my own code changes from local => dev. So maybe I don;t knwo what is hard / what I'm talking about.

So the question is: what do best practices for source control dictate? 
Am I wrong, or are they wrong? Or is the best practice somewhere in between?

Comment: They are completely nuts. Every commit should correspond to a "logical next step", which most often involves multiple files. This is a fundamental best practice of version control, and was an important part in the design of Subversion. Forcing a developer to commit file by file means they don't understand version control. Finally, a VCS is just a tool, it should not get in the way. Like I said, they are completely nuts, you need to get a new job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand the reasons why the release engineering team is doing what they're doing, but do not agree with their solution. The problem is that your process is not automated, as both you and the release team have discovered. The solution is *not* to pile on more worthless process, but to in fact, *automate* the existing delivery process.

OK, so how can this be done? Firstly, you should start associating commits with Jira issues. This can be as simple as adding a commit message of PROJ-1343 (i.e. the Jira issue that the commit is addressing). Hopefully, your current Continuous Integration process automatically builds and deploys to your Integration environment whenever you check-in, or at least at a certain interval. This will resolve problems with the build itself.

Now let's assume you've fixed all the open issues for your planned release. The problem you're release team is experiencing is that they are essentially deploying *code* by looking at line numbers and such instead of an immutable, tested build of code. You should *never* be moving/copying individual files, DLLs, etc. into an environment as that can lead to the exact problems you're already experiencing. Let your automation software handle this for you.

Naturally, as a developer for software in this space, I would recommend [BuildMaster](http://inedo.com/buildmaster). With a little investment up front in automating the delivery process, it can completely remove all the boring, repetitive tasks that lead to countless, difficult to find errors. You can then focus on building better software rather than scrolling down a page to log line numbers in your SVN or TFS commit messages. Your release team will be happy too since they know that deploying your builds to further environments will always be consistent, and there are other features in BuildMaster (such as linking BuildMaster releases to Jira releases) that can prevent deployments to certain environments unless all issues for that release are closed, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. They're off in the weeds.  Fist things first... start looking for a new job.
Next, try to be the agent of change.  You're right that changesets usually encompass one file - it actually makes it more confusing to break the commits up into multiple changesets.  Especially when one wants to revert a feature or change.

You may want to look into crucible it's the code review tool from the folks that make JIRA.  If they want to see some dialog on what was changed and why, it may help. I use it and love it.

Just a thought - your question may get put on hold or even closed.  It's pretty subjective. Anything you can do to ask specific technical questions will help with that.

Comment: I agree that it was too subjective; rather than vote to close I edited the last line to try to help it along.

Answer (score 0):

Would it help to compromise? Keep doing a single commit for a bunch of files. But instead of "one general sweeping comment" you can document what changed in each file in the commit. TortoiseSVN and other clients even give you nice autocompletion of file names involved in the commit. I think line numbers are quite excessive (that's what the "diff" command is for!) but file-by-file comments make SOME sense. You could lay out your commit message like:

```
Fixed bug 1234: floo was not flarbing correctly

floo.c: correct size passed into flarb function 
floo.h: add missing fleeble item in floo data struct
flarb.c: correct off-by-one error using size argument
```

Many tools will present the first line as a summary of the change and then you can look at the full change somehow for the details on the following lines.

Some version control systems (like Subversion) will even allow setting up a server-side hook where you could enforce that every commit includes the name of every modified file in the commit message, in case "they" are worried you'll forget to do it this way.